# Laravel Carbon Querying date with sameDay()

Tags: sql, laravel, date, php-carbon

I'm trying to build up a query method in Laravel (5.8) to retrieve the entries made in current date (think at "Discover this day" from Facebook, it's kinda the same).

I have the following code:

```
$todayMementos = Memento::where(['user_id' => auth()->user()->id])
    ->whereDate('date', Carbon::isSameDay())
    ->get();
```

I tried to compare the date with this function; I'm using Carbon "isSameDay()" for it, not sure if it's the right function to choose but the result I want is this:

If in this DD-MM-*no-matter-the-year*, user has added some entries, give them to me.

Suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrieve day current day and month

```
$day = Carbon::now()->day;
$month = Carbon::now()->month;
```

You can use Eloquent filter for retrieving the same day and month.

```
$todayMementos = Memento::where(['user_id' => auth()->user()->id])
    ->whereDay('date', '=' $day)
    ->whereMonth('date', '=', $month)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, that would work fine! But the Carbon approach seems a bit more elegant to me. Cheers.

Comment: Changed to carbon

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using carbon date formatting to get current date in yyyy-mm-dd format. This format is used by the database in sql.

```
$todayMementos = Memento::where(['user_id' => auth()->user()->id])
    ->whereDay('date',\Carbon\Carbon::now()->day)
    ->whereMonth('date',\Carbon\Carbon::now()->month)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Irrelevant, as I want to get records made in same day AS current day. eg: User have 2 posts published in 6/24/2016, and 3 in 6/24/2017. Output I want is 5 entries.

Comment: @Cicharito I am sorry about that. You have to use whereDay query. I have updated the answer. Try this one.